Minimum number of edges to be removed from a square grid so that no rectangles remain.
I encountered the following problem:
"Find the number of edges to be removed from a $8*8$ square  grid  so that no rectangles remain on the board.
I was able to use my intuition to find a formula as follows:
$ \textbf{Claim}$: The minimum number of edges to be deleted from an $n*n$ chessboard is $n^2-n+1$
$\textbf{Proof}$: We prove this by induction. Clearly, the case n=1 is trivially true.
Assume it to be true for some k sided square grid. Now add the $(k+1)^{th}$ row and column. We then remove the minimum number of squares from the $k*k$ subgrid. Then we pick the $(k+1)^{th}$ row and remove vertical edges starting with the second and ending with the $k^{th}$. Similarly we do for the $(k+1)^{th}$ column. Then we have removed $2k$ edges. It is not hard to prove that in such an L shaped configuration the minimum no. of edges to be deleted so that no rectangles are fromed is $2k$.But now observe that no more new rectangles can be formed out of the $(k+1)^{th}$ row and $(k+1)^{th}$ because we have already removed vertical edges starting with the second and ending with the $k^{th}$, except the outer square. However if we were able to complete the outer square, Then the $k*k$ sub grid square must have some 2 complete adjacent edges. In that case we can just diagonally flip the square and since the original square did not have any rectangles, the other two edges cannot be both complete , so hence we have found the minimum number of edges to be deleted, which is $k^2-k+1+2k=k^2+k+1=(k+1)^2-(k+1)+1.$
Hence by induction we are done.
I do not know if the proof is watertight as I am not acquainted with graph theory proofs. However the formula seemed to hold true for n=1,2,3. Can someone please check if my solution is correct? Also if someone has an alternative way then please share it.

Before proving anything, you should define what an edge is and what a rectangle is.  In particular, I would expect that a $1 \times 1$ grid has one node, no edges, and no rectangles, but that is inconsistent with your claim.

A 1×1 grid will be a square containing 4 edges, it's vertices will be (0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0).

OK, in graph theory that would be a $2 \times 2$ grid graph.  Now for your $n=2$, that would have $9$ nodes and $12$ edges, and you are claiming that removing $2^2-2+1=3$ edges can eliminate all rectangles.  What is a rectangle, and which $3$ edges do you remove?

Your solution is not fully logically justified. Here are two problems with your proof.

Your method does not necessarily cover all rectangles. Just look at the case $n=2$.
· - · - ·
|   |   |
· - · - ·
|   |   |
· - · - ·

You start by looking at the $1\times 1$ square grid, and remove the minimal number of edges from that. We know the solution there is to remove any single edge. Since you did not specify which one to remove, I will remove the vertical edge in the middle of the bottom row.
· - · - ·
|   |   |
· - · - ·
|       |
· - · - ·

Then, you remove the middle vertical edge of the top row, and the middle horizontal edge of the rightmost column.
· - · - ·
|       |
· - ·   ·
|       |
· - · - ·

However, we have failed, because a rectangle still exists, namely, the border around the whole grid. Note that we could have completed the first step in a different way which would make this method successful, as shown below. This shows that your proof is underspecified; you need to give more details which ensures that all of the rectangles are broken.
· - · - ·
|       |
· - ·   ·
|   |   |
·   · - ·


Secondly, in order to prove that the minimum number of edges to remove is $n^2-n+1$, you must show two things.

It is possible to break all rectangles by removing $n^2-n+1$ edges.

It is not possible to break all rectangles by removing $n^2-n$ edges.


You attempted to prove $(1)$, but you did not mention $(2)$ at all.

Right thanks, I'll see to the proof . However the formula is correct right?

I don’t really know if the formula is correct, but my intuition is saying it’s correct.
